# Convert variable reference name to its value in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm trying to access the variable reference by its name given in a String type.

```
class A {
  B b = B();
}

class B {
  String c = "apple";
}

void main() {
  
  A a = A();
  print(a.b.c); // prints apple

  /// now if I get this ref as a string eg:
  final ref = "a.b.c";

  /// want to access the same variable with its reference
  print(<ref>); <------

}
```

Need this to create a dynamic functionality.

Already tried with the creation of the `toJson()` method. but we have to access more nested classes and update all the classes with `toJson` method.

please help if there is any other solution.

Comment: You cannot do that using normal Dart (which I define as not using `dart:mirrors` or code generation). What problem are you actual trying to solve? E.g. you could use maps if you need to navigate a data structure using Strings.

Comment: I need to create a feature that will support dynamic key mapping to the API calls. and the keys will come from a config JSON. There are multiple nested classes that are already defined. so looking for a solution without the map.